# htaccess - check if original URL in the HTML contained `../`

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a directory tree that looks like:

```
public_html
    _COMMON
        INIT.php
    project-1
        index.php
    project-2
        index.php
```

Those two projects use files from _COMMON. First, they load some configuration via the following code in their index.php:

```
require_once '../_COMMON/INIT.php';
```

After that, they use common resources via:

```
<script src="../_COMMON/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

I have two domains. They are both connected to the same server, meaning they both serve the same files. I want to serve project-1 from:

```
http://example.com/project-1/
```

and

```
http://project1.com/
```

To do that, I rewrite `project1.com` URLs to `project1.com/project-1/` with the following htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?project1.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/project-1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /project-1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

---

**Problem comes here.**

The `require_once` part works because the URL of `INIT.php` is resolved *after* the request URL is rewritten, meaning:

1. User vists `http://project1.com/`
2. URL rewritten to `http://project1.com/project-1/`
3. Executing `http://project1.com/project-1/index.php`
4. `http://project1.com/project-1/index.php` with `../_COMMON/INIT.php` resolved to `http://project1.com/_COMMON/INIT.php`

However, the script isn't loaded successfully. I guess that's because the URL of `jquery.min.js` is resolved in the browser, before the URL is rewritten. I guess the following happens:

1. User vists `http://project1.com/`
2. `http://project1.com/project-1/index.php` is served, but URL is `http://project1.com/`
3. Browser sees `../_COMMON/node_modules...` and tries to resolve it
4. Browser initiates a request for `http://project1.com/_COMMON/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js`
5. URL is rewritten to `http://project1.com/project-1/_COMMON/...` **which doesn't exist**

---

### What I've tried

I could just add this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/_COMMON
```

to my htaccess and be done.

That's kind of a cheesy solution, though. What If project-1 uses a file from another directory at the root? Adding all those directories in the htaccess seems silly. I don't need to rewrite the URL if it doesn't contain `_COMMON`, I need to rewrite it if it doesn't go up the directory tree, I.E. if it contains `../`. **Is there a way to detect that?**

Basically, what I want is to **not** rewrite URLs that begin with `../`. I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.\./
```

but it doesn't work. I guess it's because that `../` is resolved in the browser, so it's not inside the URL that is actually processed by the htaccess. **Is there some other way I could detect whether the original URL contained `../`?**

Comment: `../` is not send to the server. The URL is resolved in the browser before sending.

Comment: You could try adding `RewriteEngine Off` to a .htaccess file in each folder you wish to exclude from rewrite.